# Are django session keys unique?

Tags: django

Are django session keys always unique? 
Or Do they get reused overtime? 
How does django generate the session keys?

Also, is it possible to attach create a foreign key to django's sessions table?

Answer (score 2):

Session keys are generated using random 32 character string, using only lowercase chars and digits. It is not guaranteed to be unique over time.

Since sessions may be deleted or not retained over time keys might be recycled.

And answer to fk to session is no. Since you can define backend for sessions and depending on selected session backend there might not even be database, like if using memcached or filebased or like now trending backend is to store sessions into Redis.